# How do I print certain elements of a struct in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, printing

I am trying to create a collection of car makes and models. I would like to be able to print either all the makes within my collection or all the models within my collection in Swift. Thanks in advance.

I have been able to create a small collection of car makes and models but I am struggling to work out the final part of printing certain parts of it.

```
struct Section {

 var make: String!
 var model: [String]!
}

var Cars = [

Section(make: "BMW", model: ["A","B","C"]),
Section(make: "Ford", mode: ["D","E","F"])

]

//Print a list of all makes
//Print a list of all models
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

You can use for loops:

```
// all makes
for car in Cars {
    print(car.make)
}

// all models
for car in Cars {
    for model in car.models {
        print(model)
    } 
}
```

Or you can use higher-order functions like `map` and `flatMap`:

```
// all makes
print(Cars.map { $0.make })

// all models
print(Cars.flatMap { $0.models })
```

Comment: Is there a way to store for example, all makes in a variable, sp that I can use it to populate a table view?

Comment: @TJMitch95 That is what `Cars.map { $0.make }` does.